# accessing baseURL in config file shows undefined value

Tags: javascript, protractor

below is my config file:

```
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
baseUrl1: 'https://www.angularjs.org/',
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
},
specs: ['./specs/login.spec.js'],
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
},
params: {
    baseUrl2: 'https://www.angularjs.org/',
},
onPrepare: function() {
    console.log("URL2 "+browser.params.baseUrl2);
    console.log("URL1 "+browser.baseUrl1);
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    return browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo');
    },
};
```

When I try to access with `console.log("URL1 "+browser.baseUrl1);` in onPrepare, I am getting undefined value.But Same time when I access `console.log("URL2 "+browser.params.baseUrl2);` I get the desired value, I am not sure what is the problem here. Here I want to access the baseURL value which is not part of params.

please let me know what mistake I am doing here.

Comment: Have you tried to declare baseUrl variable (with the exact name "baseUrl")?

Comment: thanks its working like a charm.

Comment: Nice, @Vinay. You should mark an answer as "resolved" ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use "baseUrl" variable, with its exact name.

```
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
baseUrl: 'https://www.angularjs.org/',
capabilities: {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, params are accessible through `browser.params.paramName` from everywhere (onPrepare, tests files...).

But you can access the baseUrl by using `exports.config.baseUrl1` if needed.

Comment: Then you should flag my post as the correct answer.